# React Link doesn't refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

Im using my react project for [ant design](https://3x.ant.design/components/layout/), when i click on  the page  header menu link page doesn't  refresh , and  i already import the
 `import {Link} from "react-router-dom";`

any solution for this?

**here the code part**

```
                               <Menu.Item key="setting:1">
                                    <Link to="/myschool">MyScool</Link>
                               </Menu.Item>
```

Comment: How you added the `Route` for this path ?

Comment: @Harikrishnan hello, Yes i already added

Comment: @core114 Does the URL change in the url bar?

Comment: Yes, its changing

Comment: Can you provide more code examples? Show where you define the routes, and where you define the BrowserRouter.